# Sorting Doubles using Comparator Program

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, switch-statement, comparator

I have developed a program that creates an array of Book Objects and sorts them based on user input. The sorting options are author-title-pages-price, and all work but the price sort. Please help me find where my application hangs... (I click the sort by price button and nothing shows up...)

My SchoolTextBook Class:

```
import java.util.Comparator;


public class SchoolTextBook {

private String author;
private String title;
private int pageCount;
private String ISBN;
private double price;

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
    }
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
    }

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
    }
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    }

public int getPageCount() {
    return pageCount;
}
public void setPageCount(int pageCount) {
    this.pageCount = pageCount;
}

public String getISBN() {
    return ISBN;
}
public void setISBN(String iSBN) {
    ISBN = iSBN;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}


public static Comparator<SchoolTextBook> BookPriceComparator 
                    = new Comparator<SchoolTextBook>() {

    public int compare(SchoolTextBook book1, SchoolTextBook book2) {

        double price1 = book1.getPrice();
        double price2 = book2.getPrice();
        //ascending order
        return Double.compare(price1, price2);

    }

};
}
```

And my SchoolTextBookSort Class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SchoolTextBookSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] choices = {"Author", "Title", "Page Count", "Price"};

    SchoolTextBook[] theBooks = new SchoolTextBook[5];

    theBooks[0] = new SchoolTextBook();
    theBooks[1] = new SchoolTextBook();
    theBooks[2] = new SchoolTextBook();
    theBooks[3] = new SchoolTextBook();
    theBooks[4] = new SchoolTextBook();

    theBooks[0].setAuthor("Ernest Hemingway");
    theBooks[1].setAuthor("Mark Twain");
    theBooks[2].setAuthor("William Shakespeare");
    theBooks[3].setAuthor("Stephen King");
    theBooks[4].setAuthor("William Faulkner");

    theBooks[0].setTitle("A Farewell to Arms");
    theBooks[1].setTitle("The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn");
    theBooks[2].setTitle("Hamlet");
    theBooks[3].setTitle("Salem's Lot");
    theBooks[4].setTitle("The Sound and the Fury");

    theBooks[0].setPageCount(332);
    theBooks[1].setPageCount(320);
    theBooks[2].setPageCount(196);
    theBooks[3].setPageCount(439);
    theBooks[4].setPageCount(326);

    theBooks[0].setISBN("0099910101");
    theBooks[1].setISBN("0142437174");
    theBooks[2].setISBN("0521618746");
    theBooks[3].setISBN("0450031063");
    theBooks[4].setISBN("0679732241");

    theBooks[0].setPrice(5.99);
    theBooks[1].setPrice(7.60);
    theBooks[2].setPrice(9.41);
    theBooks[3].setPrice(16.56);
    theBooks[4].setPrice(9.60); 


    int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
            null                                        // Center in window.
          , "Please select a method to sort the books." // Message
          , "Sort Text Books"                           // Title in titlebar
          , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION                   // Option type
          , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE                   // messageType
          , null                                        // Icon (none)
          , choices                                     // Button text as above.
          , null                                        // Default button's label
        );

    //... Use a switch statement to check which button was clicked.
    switch (response) {
    case 0: 
        Arrays.sort(theBooks, SchoolTextBook.BookAuthorComparator);
        break;
    case 1:
        Arrays.sort(theBooks, SchoolTextBook.BookTitleComparator);
        break;
    case 2:
        Arrays.sort(theBooks, SchoolTextBook.BookPagesComparator);
        break;
    case 3:
        Arrays.sort(theBooks, SchoolTextBook.BookPriceComparator);
    case -1:
        //... Both the quit button (3) and the close box(-1) handled here.
        System.exit(0);     // It would be better to exit loop, but...
    default:
        //... If we get here, something is wrong.  Defensive programming.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unexpected response " + response);
    }

    show(theBooks);


}

public static String show(SchoolTextBook[] theBooks) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
    sb.append("<html><table><tr><td>Author</td><td>Title</td><td>ISBN</td><td>Pages</td><td>Price</td></tr>");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[0].getAuthor()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[0].getTitle()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[0].getISBN()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[0].getPageCount()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append("$" + theBooks[0].getPrice()).append("</td></tr>");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[1].getAuthor()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[1].getTitle()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[1].getISBN()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[1].getPageCount()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append("$" + theBooks[1].getPrice()).append("</td></tr>");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[2].getAuthor()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[2].getTitle()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[2].getISBN()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[2].getPageCount()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append("$" + theBooks[2].getPrice()).append("</td></tr>");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[3].getAuthor()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[3].getTitle()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[3].getISBN()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[3].getPageCount()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append("$" + theBooks[3].getPrice()).append("</td></tr>");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[4].getAuthor()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[4].getTitle()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[4].getISBN()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append(theBooks[4].getPageCount()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append("$" + theBooks[4].getPrice()).append("</td>");
    sb.append("</tr></table></html>");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: I think the problem might reside in my switch statement handlers

Comment: There's no `break` for `case 3:`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959250/comparator-double-does-not-work

Comment: Not a duplicate as this is a different problem within the same program.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `break` statements to some of your `case` conditions:

```
switch (response) {
case 0: 
    Arrays.sort(theBooks, SchoolTextBook.BookAuthorComparator);
    break;
case 1:
    Arrays.sort(theBooks, SchoolTextBook.BookTitleComparator);
    break;
case 2:
    Arrays.sort(theBooks, SchoolTextBook.BookPagesComparator);
    break;
case 3:
    Arrays.sort(theBooks, SchoolTextBook.BookPriceComparator);
    break; // <---- Add this
case -1:
    //... Both the quit button (3) and the close box(-1) handled here.
    System.exit(0);     // It would be better to exit loop, but...
    break; // <---- Add this
default:
    //... If we get here, something is wrong.  Defensive programming.
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unexpected response " + response);
    break; // <---- Add this
}
```

If you don't have break statements the program continues and evaluates all of the cases lower than it as if they were true. In other words, if case 3 was true it would do the sort, then it would move on to what happens in case -1 and act as if that was true, which causes the system to exit.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the problem resides in this code here:

```
case -1:
    //... Both the quit button (3) and the close box(-1) handled here.
    System.exit(0);     // It would be better to exit loop, but...
default:
    //... If we get here, something is wrong.  Defensive programming.
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unexpected response " + response);
}
```

Not sure exactly what it is but this is what was hanging the application.